# Custom dropdown with tag and tag hover functionality

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2, dropdown

Recently a work assign to me ,that is to build a drop-down with some functionality.We use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) and try to do this because Select2 has some good features and functionality .

please see below image
[image]
[image]

1st image is initial drop-down ,with back-ground color.

and the 2nd Image has functionality

- two column drop-down items
- when a item clicked its added as tag
- and if hover-over a tag a description pop-up came out .

I am vary new to Select2 library and not understand is possible with Select2 or not?If possible please suggest me how I that can be achieved?

If not possible with Select2 please suggest other suitable library?

Please note : all item and hover-over text of tag are dynamic(from Data base)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add the `<li>` as a tag to the rest of that div (first image's outer Div). To do that, you can add the value to a variable from the `<li>` that currently clicked, then append that variable to the parent div (parent div means, for example, we can say the outer div is parent Div). This is a basic jQuery solution, actually i don't know select2. So if this answer helps you, take it.

An example also
https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/2ew27vvL/